# limit the Y-axis character in google visulaization combo graph to given limit

Tags: google-visualization

[image]Hi,
Is there any way to limit the Y-axis character in google visulaization combo graph to given limit and then ... 
By Default it is doing when more then 22 character. But I want to reduce it to given character.

Attached is the screen shot

Answer (score 0):

I assume you meant X-axis, not Y-axis, given your screen shot.  There is a quick-and-dirty approach that truncates the displayed strings to 22 characters, but this will affect the tooltips as well as the axis labels:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {
    // assumes column 0 is your labels
    var label = data.getValue(i, 0);
    label = label.substring(0, 22);
    data.setFormattedValue(i, 0, label);
}
```

If you just want to affect the axis labels, there are different approaches you can take, and which one you take depends on what you want to achieve by truncating the labels.  What is it that you want to achieve?